# don't break addEventListener when mouse is in iframe

Tags: iframe, addeventlistener

Is it possible to use addEventListener to detect mouseclicks inside an iframe? Or does iframe mean that we deal with a new document?

```
mouseButton = false;

jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){mouseButton = true;}, false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){mouseButton = false;}, false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using addEventLister on document.contentWindow